# Is it possible to have type parameters (generics) on classes which are not collections in scala?

Tags: scala

as the questions suggests. Would it ever make sense to even think about generics on non-collections? I have been trying to think this through. A collection is really just a 'wrapper' of other objects, so there has to be a 'wrapper' to direct a generic at?

thanks

Comment: Type parameters are in no way limited to collections!

Answer (score 1):

Yep.  As a minimal example, here is a class that wraps something of type `T`, where `T` is generic:

```
scala> class Wrapper[T](val x: T)
defined class Wrapper
```

If you give it an `Int`, then it's a `Wrapper[Int]`:

```
scala> new Wrapper(5)
res0: Wrapper[Int] = Wrapper@578ef2b6
```

If you give it a `String`, then it's a `Wrapper[String]`:

```
scala> new Wrapper("this")
res1: Wrapper[String] = Wrapper@3b16bf07
```

This is directly analogous to a collection of items of type `T`:

```
scala> Vector(1,2,3)
res2: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible and it makes perfect sense. Pretty much all of the type system of Scala revolves around them. Well, them and the "abstract types".

To learn more you can start [from here](http://twitter.github.io/scala_school/type-basics.html). Googling for "Scala type parameters" will also give you plenty of useful results.